# How do I loop through API keys to get output for them in separate rows in my final dataframe?

Tags: python, api, loops, dataframe

Im new to python and trying to work on looping through data:

I am using the sendgrid api global stats endpoint and I am successful in getting my output for one API key.

**My code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from datetime import date
today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sendgrid.com")
payload = "{}"
headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer SG.FO0***" }

conn.request("GET", "/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={d}&end_date={d}".format(d=today), payload, headers)

res = conn.getresponse()
data = res.read()
print(data.decode("utf-8"))

d = data.decode("utf-8")
d = json.loads(d)
d = d[0]['stats'][0]['metrics']

sendgrid = pd.DataFrame([d])
sendgrid.to_csv('sendgrid.csv')
```

**Output:**

```
sendgrid
Out[31]: 
   blocks  bounce_drops  bounces  ...  unique_opens  unsubscribe_drops  unsubscribes
0       7            14        9  ...          1240                  0             0
```

However, this is the output of one API key. I have several API keys under the same account and have different data associated with them sorted by brands:

```
#marketing = SG.UdhzjmjYRC***
#operational = SG.FO0b2Oz***
#SEOmarketing = SG._dnhFlnrSL**
#FFTP = SG.4duN1bHiT9G1**
#PPI_operational = SG.F3zH**
```

I want to loop through each of these API keys for each brand(marketing,seo marketing,etc) such that I can pull the output as above for all of them through the same app instead of creating multiple apps.
My objective is to have the final dataframe look like below:

```
Brand              blocks  bounce_drops  bounces  ...  unique_opens  unsubscribe_drops  unsubscribes
marketing           7            14        9  ...          1240                  0             0
operational         8            12        7               2000                 0              0
SEO                 15           10        8               3333                 1              0
```

What should I change or add in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you just need to create a [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesmapping) with the keys (Department Names) and values (API keys) and loop through the section where you do most of the work.

*Hint:* It's just before you set the Bearer token, and after you receive the data. You'd then join the results together in the same dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from datetime import date
today = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
import http.client

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.sendgrid.com")
payload = "{}"

keys = {
    "marketing" : "SG.UdhzjmjYRC***",
    "operational": "SG.FO0b2Oz***",
    "SEOmarketing": "SG._dnhFlnrSL**",
    "FFTP": "SG.4duN1bHiT9G1**",
    "PPI_operational": "SG.F3zH**"
}
df = []  # Create new Dataframe

for name, value in keys.items():
    headers = { 'authorization': "Bearer " + value }

    conn.request("GET", "/v3/stats?aggregated_by=day&start_date={d}&end_date={d}".format(d=today), payload, headers)

    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = res.read()
    print(data.decode("utf-8"))

    d = json.loads(data.decode("utf-8"))
    row = d[0]['stats'][0]['metrics']
    # Add Brand to data row here with 'name'
    df.append(row)  # Load data row into df

sendgrid = pd.DataFrame(df)
sendgrid.to_csv('sendgrid.csv')
```